# Error: You've provided an invalid postage policy while adding FixedPrice Listing

Tags: c#, ebay-api

While I am adding a Fixed Price Listing on eBay. It is giving following error:
No product found for ProductListingDetails.<4897010771015>
You've provided an invalid postage policy.

But by using the same c# code, I have added multiple similar types of listings before.
But now it is giving the above error.

May I get a quick reason and solution for the above error.

Comment: The error seems quite obvious `You've provided an invalid postage policy`, but without code I have no idea what you are doing wrong.

Comment: But by using the same c# code, I have added multiple similar types of listings before.

Comment: BTW, I could be a lot more detailed in my answer if you update the question with more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are basically three possible reasons for this error.  I can't tell which one applies because you didn't really post any details in the question.

One, your secret code has a subtle bug that wasn't tripped with previous listings.  Resolution:  Debug your code.

Two, eBay made a change to their postage policy or listing validation code, and your listings are no longer valid under the new rules.  Resolution:  Update your code to comply with the latest changes.

Three, eBay updated their servers with code that contains a bug in the logic for validating postage policies.  Resolution:  Wait for eBay to fix the bug.